# Why can't I access overridden public fields in an anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes, scriptengine

I have a class that I can't change as follows:

```
public class Foo {
    public final int ID=0;
    public int bar;
    public final Object baz=null;
}
```

I want to have an anonymous inner class that overrides `Foo` such as:

```
public Foo newFoo(final int mID, final int mbar, final Object mbaz) {
    return new Foo(){
        public final int ID = mID;
        public int bar = mbar;
        public final Object baz = mbaz;
    };
}
```

I then have a `javax.script.ScriptEngine` that I want to call something like this in JS: `newFoo(0,0,undefined)["ID"]`

My problem is that I get an exception like this:

```
sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.JavaMembers can not access a member of class Baz$1 with modifiers "public final" (mod.js#9) in test.js at line number 9
```

I don't understand how I could be getting a problem here: this works just fine if `newFoo` returns a plain 'ol `Foo`, but if I try to override `Foo` with an anonymous inner class, I can't access any overridden members even if they're public.

Comment: What you're doing seems "odd", but I'd start with the error message which is telling you about the final int ID - your anon constructor is trying to set a final again. Perhaps try making ID non final.

Comment: You can't do this and the error message is telling you why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two aspects to this problem.

Your Java code is syntactically valid (I think), but it almost certainly does not do what you want it to do.  Specifically, the declarations in the anonymous class don't replace the declarations in the `Foo` class.  Instead, each instance of the anonymous class gets two sets of fields.  The methods declared in `Foo` will only see the original fields, and any methods declared in the anonymous class will see the new fields.

If you want to have different values for the fields in the anonymous subclass, then:

- they cannot be final, and
- they need to be assigned to not redeclared.

I can't really advise the best way to solve this, but I think you will need to *start* by making the `Foo` fields private, and providing getters and/or setters for them.  In the case of the setters, you can use access modifiers to allow the anonymous subclass to set the field, but not unrelated code.

The bottom line is that you **cannot** *override* fields in Java.  What your code is doing is not overriding, it is *hiding* the fields.

---

The other aspect is the wrapped exception is coming from the Javascript engine.  I think that the problem is that anonymous classes are implicitly private, and that your Javascript snippet is therefore trying to access a field on a private class.  When the Javascript engine tries to do this (using Java reflection, I expect), it gets a runtime exception.

The only unfortunate thing here is that the exception message doesn't say *why* it can't access the member, but your Java code is sufficiently "strange" that this doesn't surprise me.

As a work-around, I'd suggest replacing the anonymous class with a non-nested class.

Answer (score -2):

You don't have a class like this :

```
public class Foo {
    public final int ID=0;
    public int bar;
    public final Object baz;
}
```

Because that wouldn't compile (baz cannot not be declared).

Comment: It's legal to declare a final field without an initializer. It's called a *blank final*. The requirement is that the field be initialized exactly once in all constructors and instance initializers. Presumably the OP omitted these from the example for the sake of brevity.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be clever for clevers sake. The OP was asking specifically about how to override fields, some of which were unassigned final fields. Since that was absolutely relevant to the question it's important he posted the "real" code. I notice he's now edited it.